# Why is one div displaying below a sidebar instead of to the side?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, 960.gs

I'm working on a site that has grid-16 to start with. I increased the grid size by a factor of 4/3, and  have altered the markup. Adding float to either element does not appear to be doing anything.

The page is the homepage at http://ccachicago.pragmatometer.com/. I'm trying to get the main content area to display to the left of the sidebar, instead of having its top of the sidebar's bottom. I'm sorry not to provide singled-out HTML and CSS, but the page has a lot of inherited CSS, and I'm working on getting on top of it.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `width: 1306px;`

```
#main, #page-inner, #main-group {background-color: #fff; width: 1306px;}
#main, #page-inner, #main-group {background-color: #fff;}
```